# How to transform a vector of size N into a column vector of size N(N-1)/2?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, linear-algebra

I am following a procedure in which:

•   I built a square matrix by *stacking* a column vector.

•   Compare the matrix with its transpose to obtain a square, binary matrix.

•   *Vectorize* the upper or lower triangular part of the binary matrix into a column vector of length *N(N-1)/2*.

Current code is not quite correct yet, as the size does not equal *N(N-1)/2*:

```
arr = np.array([2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2])

bin_nums = ((arr.reshape(-1,1) & (2**np.arange(8))) != 0).astype(int)
bin_nums = bin_nums[:,::-1]

a = bin_nums
a_T = bin_nums.transpose()

b = (a == a_T).astype(int)

c = b[np.triu_indices(8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

# Vector of size N
vector = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# Size of the vector
N = len(vector)

# Size of the column vector
col_vector_size = N * (N - 1) // 2

# Transform the vector into a column vector
col_vector = np.zeros((col_vector_size, 1))

# Copy the vector into the column vector
k = 0
for i in range(N):
 for j in range(i + 1, N):
  col_vector[k] = vector[i] * vector[j]
  k += 1
# Result
print(col_vector)
```

Comment: This is not correct, because the col_vector would have to be 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the diagonal in [`triu_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) with `k=1`:

```
b = (a == a.T).astype(int)

c = b[np.triu_indices(arr.shape[0], k=1)]
# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
#        1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])


N = arr.shape[0]
assert len(c) == N*(N-1)/2
```

Comment: from a linear algebra perspective, comparing a with a_T, does this imply substraction or '=='?

Comment: @Sean_TBI_Research I just used your logic, I don't know what you want to do in detail, but N*(N-1)/2 means you want to exclude the diagonal

Comment: Is there a way to also consider the [0,0] entry of the pair confusion matrix?

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = np.array([2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2])

n = len(arr)
arr = arr.repeat(n)
arr =arr.reshape(n, n)

a = arr
a_T = arr.transpose()

b = (a == a_T).astype(int)

c = b[np.triu_indices(arr.shape[0], k=1)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this recursively for multiple arrays and append the columns together in a single data frame?